# QAction size PyQt5

Tags: python, button, pyqt5

```py
from PyQt5 import Qt
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from sys import argv


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('https://www.duckduckgo.com'))
        self.browser.urlChanged.connect(self.update_AddressBar)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

        self.navigation_bar = QToolBar('Navigation Toolbar')
        self.addToolBar(self.navigation_bar)
        self.navigation_bar.setAttribute(Qt.Qt.WA_StyledBackground, True)
        self.navigation_bar.setStyleSheet('background-color: white;')
        self.navigation_bar.setMinimumSize(0, 75)
        self.navigation_bar.setMovable(False)

        back_button = QAction("←", self)
        back_button.setStatusTip('Go to previous page you visited')
        back_button.triggered.connect(self.browser.back)
        self.navigation_bar.addAction(back_button)

        next_button = QAction("→", self)
        next_button.setStatusTip('Go to next page')
        next_button.triggered.connect(self.browser.forward)
        self.navigation_bar.addAction(next_button)

        refresh_button = QAction("⟳", self)
        refresh_button.setStatusTip('Refresh this page')
        refresh_button.triggered.connect(self.browser.reload)
        self.navigation_bar.addAction(refresh_button)

        home_button = QAction("⌂", self)
        home_button.setStatusTip('Go to home page (Google page)')
        home_button.triggered.connect(self.go_to_home)
        self.navigation_bar.addAction(home_button)

        #self.navigation_bar.addSeparator()

        self.URLBar = QLineEdit()
        self.URLBar.returnPressed.connect(lambda: self.go_to_URL(QUrl(self.URLBar.text())))  # This specifies what to do when enter is pressed in the Entry field
        self.navigation_bar.addWidget(self.URLBar)

        self.addToolBarBreak()

        self.show()

    def go_to_home(self):
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('https://www.duckduckgo.com/'))

    def go_to_URL(self, url: QUrl):
        if url.scheme() == '':
            url.setScheme('http://')
        self.browser.setUrl(url)
        self.update_AddressBar(url)

    def update_AddressBar(self, url):
        self.URLBar.setText(url.toString())
        self.URLBar.setCursorPosition(0)


app = QApplication(argv)
app.setApplicationName('Libertatem Browser')

window = Window()
app.exec_()
```

As you can see in my code, I have 4 QActions.  I want to make these bigger.  How can I do that?  I have seen others using `back_button.geometry()`, but you can't do that with QActions.

I would prefer to keep them as QActions, because it took me a long while to set them up.  As a side note, would changing the font size make the button bigger?

Comment: Your question is unclear, also considering that QAction is not a widget, so you probably mean QToolButton. How do you create those buttons, from code or through Designer? What do you mean by "resize these in some way"? Are you using layout managers? Have you tried to set a fixed size ([`setFixedSize()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedSize-1))? If you are creating the ui from code, please provide a [mre], otherwise share the ui file (it's an XML file, open it in a text editor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the size of the button associated with the QAction it would not make a big difference, you could do it in the following way:

```py
button = toolbar.widgetForAction(action)
button.setFixedSize(100, 100)
```

But in this case it is better to change the font size since the size of the button (and the height of the QToolBar) depends on it.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl, QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QApplication, QLineEdit, QMainWindow, QToolBar
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.duckduckgo.com"))
        self.browser.urlChanged.connect(self.update_AddressBar)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)

        self.navigation_bar = QToolBar("Navigation Toolbar", movable=False)
        self.addToolBar(self.navigation_bar)
        self.navigation_bar.setAttribute(Qt.WA_StyledBackground, True)
        self.navigation_bar.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")

        font = QFont()
        font.setPixelSize(40)

        back_action = QAction("←", self)
        back_action.setStatusTip("Go to previous page you visited")
        back_action.triggered.connect(self.browser.back)
        back_action.setFont(font)
        self.navigation_bar.addAction(back_action)

        next_action = QAction("→", self)
        next_action.setStatusTip("Go to next page")
        next_action.triggered.connect(self.browser.forward)
        next_action.setFont(font)
        self.navigation_bar.addAction(next_action)

        refresh_action = QAction("⟳", self)
        refresh_action.setStatusTip("Refresh this page")
        refresh_action.triggered.connect(self.browser.reload)
        refresh_action.setFont(font)
        self.navigation_bar.addAction(refresh_action)

        home_action = QAction("⌂", self)
        home_action.setStatusTip("Go to home page (Google page)")
        home_action.setFont(font)
        home_action.triggered.connect(self.go_to_home)
        self.navigation_bar.addAction(home_action)

        self.URLBar = QLineEdit()
        self.URLBar.returnPressed.connect(self.handle_return_pressed)
        self.navigation_bar.addWidget(self.URLBar)

    def go_to_home(self):
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.duckduckgo.com/"))

    def go_to_URL(self, url: QUrl):
        if url.scheme() == "":
            url.setScheme("http://")
        self.browser.setUrl(url)
        self.update_AddressBar(url)

    def update_AddressBar(self, url):
        self.URLBar.setText(url.toString())
        self.URLBar.setCursorPosition(0)

    def handle_return_pressed(self):
        url = QUrl.fromUserInput(self.URLBar.text())
        self.go_to_URL(url)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("Libertatem Browser")

    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```